# Failure to change android language

Tags: android

I have the below codde that i am tring to update the androis language

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
// Change locale settings in the app.
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.setLocale(new Locale(language_code.toLowerCase())); // API 17+ only.
// Use conf.locale = new Locale(...) if targeting lower versions
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

But seem not to be working as the language is not changing.
what can be the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-app-language-programmatically-in-android Try this one... There has been some updates in 2021

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code
`conf.setLayoutDirection(new Locale(language_code.toLowerCase()));`
Here is [source code](https://github.com/orbitalsonic/App-Language-Change-Android-Kotlin) of change language in app it will help you.

**Note**

this method is useful on your debugging apk and signed `.apk` but it is not working on the bundle file because Google also split bundle files on the basis of language. and you should `enableSplit = false` in `build.gradle`

```
 bundle {
        language {
            // Specifies that the app bundle should not support
            // configuration APKs for language resources. These
            // resources are instead packaged with each base and
            // dynamic feature APK.
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
```